# Use the value of global variable in any other function as its value changes inside another function

Tags: c, function, global-variables

say i am using a global variable to hold the value of a signal (in a schematics for a circuit board sense)  in one function

```
void randomfunction()
{
    for(t=lnnew,s=node->name;*s;)
    {
    if()
         //some code

    else
      *t=*s;
    t++;
    s++;
    }
printf("%s \n",lnnew);   //so now here lnnew is holding new values of signal and when i print this, every time new value of signal is printed and i have declared it as global
}
```

now how can i use this global variable inside any other function say `writelnnewvalue()` so that when ever value of lnnew changes in `randomfunction()`, it also get changes and printed in `writelnnewvalue ()` function?

I had asked similar type of question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609098/unable-to-print-the-value-of-global-variable-in-another-function) , if it seems to be exact copy then mark it as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to print the value of global variable in another function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609098/unable-to-print-the-value-of-global-variable-in-another-function)

Comment: What exactly is not workng as intended ?

Comment: @shodanex: i am unable to print the value of lnnew in my second function, indeed only last assigned value get printed instead of all the values

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable in a header (`.h` file) that is included in all compilation units that use it:

```
extern volatile int lnnew;
```

Have one compilation unit (`.c` file) actually define it

```
volatile int lnnew;
```

Then it will be usable everywhere where you include the header. `volatile` here indicates to the compiler that that variable is subject to unpredictable changes and is not to be cached.

Comment: I think according to question, some interrupt sort of behaviour is required. Whenever value changes at one place, it triggers a print at other place. Please correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Sergey L: So you are using int , shouldn't it has to be char.And i should use it in the file where i am using this variable.

Comment: @nishant I think signal is misleading here, it is a signal in an electronic schematic, not an OS signal

Comment: @shailendra it can be any type. I just put `int` because it's the most generic, but any is permitted (can even be a struct or something more complicated). If you are using it in only one `.c` file (compilation unit) then you only need to put it there, but it can be used across multiple files if you include the header with the `extern` declaration in all of them. Just make sure to define it in the global scope.

Comment: @shodanex : Yes, I understood the same, but what I said was according to the lines in the question after the code.

Comment: @SergeyL: Its not a OS signal, its only a name.Like wise lnnew = vdd, lnew = vcc, lnnew = gnd, so these value are being populated in lnnew inside randomfunction() and when i use lnnew which is declared volatile global, inside another function only the last value get print

Comment: My question has been changed totally. i don't know why, lnnew is only holding a string, i had used signal because the string which it is holding can be vcc, vdd, gnd or anything extra

Comment: @SergeyL.: Now i am not using global variable, rather i am passing that local variable of one function as a argument to another function using char lnnew and output is only garbage value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use two different threads to perform these tasks. Use a flag which is updated on the change of `lnnew` in one thread (which will run `randomfunction()`) & use other thread (which will run `writelnnewvalue()`) conditioned on this flag, to print whatever is desired.

You can find more about multithreaded programming on Internet. A few links I found:
[Link 1](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html)
[Link 2](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Link 1 has code examples with explanation.

Comment: @shailendra : Sorry for being late in reply. I have added few links in my answer